# print preview of different page formats

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I have a winform application where you can select a page via a combobox item. Everytime a page is selected , the corresponding panel is being displayed. Every page can have different formats like A4, Landscape or A3 .

So when I click the "Print" button, I create an image for of each panel content and store it in a list, so that I can access it in the PrintPage event handler.

Now what I want is, that in the printpreview dialog, those pages should be shown in the correct format like a4, a3 or landscape.

Is this possible ? If so, how can I change the format for each displayed page ?

Comment: Hard to make sense of this, printers are not usually very happy with having to pick a different paper size for each individual page in a document.  Do use PageSetupDialog first, the normal way that a user selects his preference.  The PrintDocument.QueryPageSettings event next.

Comment: Like @HansPassant says, what you're proposing sounds pretty strange. It just might be feasible for a locally-attached printer, but any kind of printing over the network involves creating a single print spool file that contains the entire document, and all pages will have the same page setup. Or else you'll be creating many print spool files, and your pages may get printed intermingled with other users' printed documents.

Comment: You can do it if you want to by setting `e.PageSettings.PaperSize` and `e.PageSettings.Landscape` at the start of the `printDoc_PrintPage` event to the settings you want for each page. Of course a real printer will not be able to follow varying settings, but printing to pdf work just fine this way.. If you also set `e.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.PaperSources` you may probably event use as many paper sizes as your printer has feeds..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you for your comments, which helped me a lot !!

I skipped the preview dialog and created a PrintDocument for each page, where as each PrintDocument was then sent to the printer by the PrintDocument.Print() call.

I have set the PaperSize and Landscape manually and it worked for me !

Many thanks !!